# Convert xml to dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

in my web application, i get result as xml when display on web browser like this

```
<Responses>
<Response0>
    <Action>sendMessage</Action>
    <Data>
        <AcceptReport>
            <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
            <StatusText>Message accepted for delivery</StatusText>
            <MessageID>89c8011c-e291-44c3-ac72-cd35c76cb29d</MessageID>
            <Recipient>+85568922903</Recipient>
        </AcceptReport>
    </Data>
</Response0>
</Responses>
```

i want above XML file display as text like below:

```
Message accepted for delivery
Message ID: IEUHSHIL
Recipient: +441234567
```

how can i convert xml file to text above?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean - do you mean you have a web page on which you are writing string value and it's coming out like this?  Or do you mean you are returning the XML to the browser and it's displaying the whole thing as XML (i.e. in IE you get the collapsible XML tree) - if the latter then you probably want to look at XSL

Comment: i mean have a web page on which you are writing string value and it's coming out like this. so how can i do?

Comment: Hi i updated my answer with full soruce ..just check it .. dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Comment: @ToeurTenh Why did [you ask this question *again*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879153/translate-xml-file-to-text)?  Admittedly that version is better than this one - so you need to edit this one with the details of the other please.

Comment: sorry becuase during i am editing this posting , when i click on save edition, it can not process. i don't know because of what that why i make one more question

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

*Source Code*

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Responses> <Response0>     <Action>sendMessage</Action>     <Data>         <AcceptReport>             <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>             <StatusText>Message accepted for delivery</StatusText>             <MessageID>89c8011c-e291-44c3-ac72-cd35c76cb29d</MessageID>             <Recipient>+85568922903</Recipient>         </AcceptReport>     </Data> </Response0> </Responses> ");

var message = from item in doc.Descendants("AcceptReport")
               select new { 
                    StatusText = item.Element("StatusText").Value,
                    MessageID = item.Element("MessageID").Value,
                    Recipient = item.Element("Recipient").Value 
               };
foreach (var el in message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el.MessageID + " " +el.Recipient + " " + el.StatusText);
}
```

Note : make use of `XDocument.Parse` if you are passing string instead of xml file.

---

Easy way to do it make use of `Linq To XML`.

Check over there : [**Reading XML documents using LINQ to XML**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1524/reading-xml-documents-using-linq-to-xml/)

not sure but something like this

```
var message=  
              from item in XElement.Load("message.xml").Descendants("Data") 
                 select new
                 {
                      StatusText= item.Element("StatusText").Value,
                      MessageID= item.Element("MessageID").Value,
                      Recipient= item.Element("Recipient").Value
                  };
```

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: @ToeurTenh - i paste link over there.. you can also google like linq to xml read will give you no of article to do this..

Comment: Thanks Nikhil and Rana: ok i will read

Comment: @Rana: I don't have xml file. i mean that after i run my web application it display result as xml doc. how can i do?

Comment: @ToeurTenh - you can pass xml string inpalce of file.

Comment: sorry i'm not understand well can you more explain?

Comment: @ToeurTenh - i updated my answer with full soruce ..just check it.... dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Comment: @ToeurTenh - dont forget to upvtoe and mark it as accepted...if it works ..